2sxc mobius forms allow user to edit submissions
I want to use mobius form builder to allow DNN users to submit information, including a file upload, and come back later to see and edit (only) their form submission. Those in a designated DNN admin role would be able to see and edit any submission. All users would be logged in to DNN. I'm trying to use the form builder features (without creating a bespoke content type and views) and the dynamic form and dynamic data razor templates. Is this possible or would I need to create custom content types and views to provide editing capabilities?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Mobius isn't meant for this two way scenario, as it "removes" a lot of data management features which 2sxc provides.
For example: 2sxc has a concept of an Entity-owner, which is the person who created an item. This concept allows you to find all items which this person created (using the owner-filter in Visual Query), or allows you to provide edit-permissions in the normal edit-dialog to the owner.
So Mobius isn't the way to go here, just use the built in standard functionality.

Got it, thanks for the answer.
